# How do I get gphoto2 to fetch a photo from a Sony alpha 6000?

Tags: camera, timelapse

How do I get [gphoto2](http://www.gphoto.org/) to fetch a photo from a [Sony alpha 6000](http://store.sony.com/alpha-a6000/cat-27-catid-All-Alpha-a6000-Cameras)?

I'm currently running gphoto2 on a [Beaglebone black](http://beagleboard.org/Products/BeagleBone+Black), but I suspect it should work on any Linux system with a USB port.

I use

```
gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --force-overwrite --filename test.jpg
```

with another camera to pull in a snapshot.
But when I unplug that camera and plug in the Sony alpha 6000 to the same USB port and run the same command, gphoto2 tells me

```
ERROR: Could not capture image.
ERROR: Could not capture.
```

While trying to debug, I try

```
gphoto2 --abilities
```

and then gphoto2 responds with

```
Abilities for camera             : Sony Alpha-A6000
Serial port support              : no
USB support                      : yes
Capture choices                  :
                                 : Image
Configuration support            : yes
Delete selected files on camera  : yes
Delete all files on camera       : no
File preview (thumbnail) support : yes
File upload support              : yes
```

When I type

```
gphoto2 --set-config f-number=8
```

and then repeat the command a few times,
I see the f-number on the LCD screen of the camera change every time I run the command, one step closer to 8, until it reaches "F8.0".

When I type

```
gphoto2 --get-config f-number
```

then gphoto2 tells me

```
Label: F-Number
Type: RANGE
Current: 8
Bottom: 0
Top: 655.35
Step: 0.01
```

So apparently gphoto2 is recognizing that this is a "Sony Alpha-A6000" and I'm getting two-way communication over the USB cable.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add your attempts in the question so people won't suggest things you've already done.

Comment: Have you tried reading the gphoto2 documentation, the wiki, asking for support there?  This seems to be more of a software question that a photography one.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me if there's a better way than this:

Edit `libgphoto2-2.5.4\camlibs\ptp2\library.c`
and add the lines marked by "+":

```
    {"Sony:Alpha-A3000",          0x054c, 0x074e, 0},
+        
+   /* Sony alpha 6000: JB and DC added 2014-05-19 */
+   {"Sony:Alpha-A6000",          0x054c, 0x094e, PTP_CAP},
 
    /* Nikon Coolpix 2500: M. Meissner, 05 Oct 2003 */
```

Then run:

```
cd libgphoto2-2.5.4
make
sudo make install
```

To install that library where gphoto2 can find it.

---

**Important**: Turn the mode dial on the top of the camera to "Superior Auto".
It definitely *won't* take snapshots with the mode dial in the "Movie" position.

Then:

```
gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --force-overwrite --filename test.jpg
```